# Tryus websocket client - onMessage does not get called although connection is succesful

Tags: websocket, tyrus

I am successfully connecting to a local websocket server with `tyrus`, but the `onMessage` method does not get called. I setup Fiddler as proxy in between and I see that the server responds with two messages, however, they are not printed out in my code. I more or less adapted the sampe code:
The `onOpen` Message is printed out

```
public static void createAndConnect(String channel) {

    CountDownLatch messageLatch;
    try {
        messageLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        final ClientEndpointConfig cec = ClientEndpointConfig.Builder.create().build();
        ClientManager client = ClientManager.createClient();
        client.connectToServer(new Endpoint() {

            @Override
            public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config) {
                System.out.println("On Open and is Open " + session.isOpen());

                session.addMessageHandler((Whole<String>) message -> {
                    System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
                    messageLatch.countDown();
                });
            }
        }, cec, new URI("ws://192.168.1.248/socket.io/1/websocket/" + channel));
        messageLatch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //I also tried increasing timeout to 30sec, doesn't help 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

[image: Web Socket response in Fiddler]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known issue - it will work if you rewrite lambda to anonymous class or use [Session#addMessageHandler(Class, MessageHandler)](https://tyrus-project.github.io/apidocs-javax.websocket/1.1/javax/websocket/Session.html#addMessageHandler(java.lang.Class,%20javax.websocket.MessageHandler.Whole)) (you can use lambdas here).

Comment: Thanks. So if I understand you correctly, I need to change the add message handler back to an anonymous class?

Comment: that's one option. Or, if you are using websocket 1.1, then you can do:                 session.addMessageHandler(String.class, (Whole<String>) message -> {
                    System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
                    messageLatch.countDown();
                });

Comment: The `String.class` argument fixed it for me. Thanks!